# Converting JSON Data in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net

I am trying to convert [This Data](https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=BTC_ETH&start=0&end=9999999999&period=86400) to a structure.

I have the structure as so:

```
Public Structure cChartData
    Public cUDate As String
    Public cOpen As Double
    Public cClose As Double
    Public cHigh As Double
    Public cLow As Double
End Structure
```

and the class as so:

```
Friend Class ChartData
Public Property uDate() As String
    Get
        Return m_date
    End Get
    Set
        m_date = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_date As String
Public Property high() As String
    Get
        Return m_high
    End Get
    Set
        m_high = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_high As String
Public Property low() As String
    Get
        Return m_low
    End Get
    Set
        m_low = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_low As String
Public Property open() As String
    Get
        Return m_open
    End Get
    Set
        m_open = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_open As String
Public Property close() As String
    Get
        Return m_close
    End Get
    Set
        m_close = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_close As String
Public Property volume() As String
    Get
        Return m_volume
    End Get
    Set
        m_volume = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_volume As String
Public Property quoteVolume() As String
    Get
        Return m_quoteVolume
    End Get
    Set
        m_quoteVolume = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_quoteVolume As String
Public Property weightedAverage() As String
    Get
        Return m_weightedAverage
    End Get
    Set
        m_weightedAverage = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_weightedAverage As String
End Class
```

I am trying to retrieve all variables from each line. I get all of them except the date. I am using the following code (where chartInfo = JSON Data):

```
Dim cdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of ChartData))(chartInfo)
        Dim cResData(cdata.Count - 1) As cChartData
        For i = 0 To cdata.Count - 1
            cResData(i).cUDate = cdata(i).uDate
            cResData(i).cOpen = Convert.ToDouble(cdata(i).open)
            cResData(i).cClose = Convert.ToDouble(cdata(i).close)
            cResData(i).cHigh = Convert.ToDouble(cdata(i).high)
            cResData(i).cLow = Convert.ToDouble(cdata(i).low)
        Next
        Return cResData
```

The date returns a "blank" value, or nothing, when displayed, but all other values return properly. It is the first value so I wonder if it has something to do with it...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a property can be serialized it will be be left null by the JSON serializer.

So either the dates in your JSON are empty or null or they are in a DateFormat that .NET can't serialize by default.

In your posted JSON, the date field is what is numeric format, such as '1438992000' meaning it is a timestamp.

Additionally, the field name is 'date' but you have defined your property as `uDate`. For serialization to work the property name must match the JSON key unless you are overriding the default serialization. Change the definition as follows and it will serialize:

```
    Public Property [date] As String
    Get
        Return m_date
    End Get
    Set
        m_date = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: I have posted the JSON data being used as a hyperlink in the main post....

Comment: Sorry, didn't see it. Updated my answer.

Comment: Problem was naming as "date", but using [date] works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get "empty" value for `uDate` property is that porperty names should match for successful deserialization.

You can change property name to satisfy  this rule. But if you want keep property names in class as it is - you can use `JsonPropertyAttribute` for json names.

```vb
Public Class ChartData

    <JsonProperty("date")>
    Public Property uDate As String

    <JsonProperty("high")>
    Public Property high As String

End Class
```

With attributes you can use different naming conventions for different code environments. For example "PascalCase" in .NET and "camelCase" in JSON